# Expedia Travel Insurance in Stereo

Tags: insurance

I cancelled flights on Spirit booked through Expedia with travel insurance. I find myself with two different policies; one with Aon visible on the Expedia site, and one with AIG that showed up with the Spirit booking. I don't understand this; I only clicked one box, as far as I recall. Upon cancelling the 'non-refundable, non-changeable, non-tranferrable' tickets, I was surprised to be told that I was receiving a credit for most of the cost. This is actually bad news, as I have no possibly way to use that credit in the 60 days it is good for.

So, this question has two parts: (1) are these policies redundant, or do they cover complementary aspects of the situation, (2) are they likely to refuse to pay the money covered by the useless credit?

Comment: Who issued you the credit? Expedia? Spirit? Someone else?

Answer (score 2):

Most insurance policies cover what monies you lose, so likely the airline credit value would be deducted from any insurance pay out.  It doesn't matter that you think a credit is 'useless'.

As for the policies being redundant or complementary, that is impossible for anyone here to answer, you just have to read the coverage details on the policies.

And of course all the above depends on why you cancelled and again the terms of your coverage.